# Additional Information managable via dashboard

Tags: magento-1.7, static-block, cms-block, additional-information

I am using additional.phtml to add some custom extra information to 1 best-of-product of mine - like images, videos or text and I do this by hardcoded adding of markup-code directly to the additional.phtml-file in a separate sub-package - ouch, I know. Now I want to extend this functionality to more products and I am wondering, if this isn't doable via the dashboard directly to also keep it managable more easily.

Therefore I added 3 CMS static block in the dashboard and `would like to integrate block_1 into product_1's page and block_2 into product_2's page` ... and I use this in the additional.phtml-file of my theme

```
<? echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_1')->toHTML(); ?>
```

But I have no clue on how to now define, that block_1 shall be shown on product_1 etc. Where would I need to do that? In the dashboard?

---

### **UPDATED**

Based on the given hint of Amit, I added a new attribute and some cms-blocks and I am doing this now in my additional.phtml-file

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
if (!$_category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    $_product = Mage::getSingleton( 'catalog/product' )->load( $_product->getId() );
}
$_product->getSetCms(); 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product)->toHTML(); ?>
```

But I do get a: *Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object* 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ideall to create an product attribute and then  assign the block ids to  product attribute value

Comment: Thanks for that idea. So I would create a new attribute and assign a special value to it > getthisvalue in my additional.phtml-file > and use it like this 
<? echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($value_ofattribute)->toHTML(); ?>

Comment: Do you have product in $this? Maybe get it the same way as category? $_product = Mage::registry('current_product')